# React.JS setup with Codeigniter

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, codeigniter-3

I'm planning to have **Codeigniter** and **Reactjs** for my new project,

> I need to know how to setup the project folders and the build process
>   for the `.jsx` files to be `.js` and then all the `.js` files to be
>   concatenated and minified to be `min.js` and also using `ES6 Style`.

I am using NPM, please explain in details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter and React.JS setup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30504206/codeigniter-and-react-js-setup)

Comment: That's not Solve my problem for creating complete project using npm